# Incorrect when using openGL to show GPUImageOutput's BRGA data, 1920*1080

Tags: ios, opengl-es, gpuimage

[image]
For newcomer to OpengGL, this accident always has something wrong with imageWidth.
GPUImageOutput's data size isn't equal to image.width* image.height * bitsPerPixel. In some code, you may see that codes, but it's wrong...
It's a pit.

**Use glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH) to set row length, not bytesPerRow.**

Tip:
how to debug:

```
#define ASSERT(xx) NSAssert1(xx, @"code:0x%x", glGetError());
ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
```

**question's history:**
yesterday night:
I found it. when image size is 1920*1080,  the RawDataOutput.bytesPerRow is 4352, not 4320(1080*4). so image is incorrect..
Next question is how to use glTexImage2d to set the bytesPerRow?

yestorday afternoon:
I'm using GPUImageRawDataOutput's data to create one Image.
When the camera's dimension is 1280*720 or 640*480, it's Ok; but with 1920*1080, it has something wrong.
I modified KxMovieView to show the data by OpenGL view, it has the same wrong. Then I modifiy kxMovieView to show one image which I got from internet, it's ok.
I'm puzzled! I guess it may has some wrong with image.linesize, but no help.

GPUImageRawDataOutput's image format is BGRA. kxMovieView default support RGB, I only change it to RGBA, and in shader, add .bgra to it.

```
//shader:  
NSString *const zvertexShaderString = SHADER_STRING  
(  
 attribute vec4 position;  
 attribute vec2 texcoord;  
 uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;  
 varying vec2 v_texcoord;  

 void main()  
 {  
     gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;  
     v_texcoord = texcoord.xy;  
 }  
);  

NSString *const zrgbFragmentShaderString = SHADER_STRING  
(
 varying highp vec2 v_texcoord;  
 uniform sampler2D s_texture;  

 void main()  
 {  
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, v_texcoord).bgra;  
 }  
);
```

//KxGLRenderer_RGB
    - (NSString *) fragmentShader
    {
        return zrgbFragmentShaderString;
    }

```
- (void) resolveUniforms: (GLuint) program
{
    _uniformSampler = glGetUniformLocation(program, "s_texture");
}

- (void) setFrame: (KxVideoFrame *) frame
{
    KxVideoFrameRGB *rgbFrame = (KxVideoFrameRGB *)frame;

    assert(rgbFrame.rgb.length == rgbFrame.width * rgbFrame.height * 4);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    if (0 == _texture)
        glGenTextures(1, &_texture);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                 0,
                 GL_RGBA,
                 (GLsizei)frame.width,
                 (GLsizei)frame.height,
                 0,
                 GL_RGBA,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 rgbFrame.rgb.bytes);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}

- (BOOL) prepareRender
{
    if (_texture == 0)
        return NO;

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);
    glUniform1i(_uniformSampler, 0);

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Too many code and I only  edit little code of kxMovieView to show GPUImageRawDataOutput's data.  GPUImageView's output put is right. so I want to know, what's wrong with GPUImageRawDataOutput's data.

Answer (score 1):

GPU hardware may require stride that doesn't match exactly image width. GPUImageRawDataOutput handles that correctly when reporting width that doesn't match image width.

You can tell GL that your image data has stride different to width with [glPixelStorei](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glPixelStorei.xhtml)(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH)